# Синонимизировать и объединить [osm] и [OpenStreetMap], [nuxt] и [Nuxt.js]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить и синонимизировать метки:

- [osm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osm) -> [openstreetmap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstreetmap)
- [nuxt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt) -> [nuxt.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js)